# 0–127 range limit on WEXITSTATUS in old Unix?

Tags: c, history, posix

It is well known that, on many if not all Unixes, a process's exit status will be truncated to its lowest 8 bits when passed through `_exit`, `waitpid`, and `WEXITSTATUS`.  (Current iterations of POSIX specify that the status should *not* be truncated when passed through `_exit` and `waitid`, but that's not relevant to this question.)

Was it ever the case, possibly *deep* in the past, that the exit status would be truncated to its lowest *seven* bits when passed through whatever mechanism was the equivalent of `_exit`/`waitpid`/`WEXITSTATUS` at the time?  If so, on which historical implementation(s) was that, and how long ago?

Comment: If you're thinking of advice to stick to 7-bit exit statuses, that's not because of some older systems that truncated to 7 bits, but because of the shell interface, which doesn't allow to distinguish between “died due to signal N” and “exited normally with status 128+N”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

7-bit would be an unusual departure from the PDP-11, which [according to the unix 2nd edition manual](http://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Distributions/Research/1972_stuff/unix_2nd_edition_manual.pdf) (p.144) dropped the exit status into

> The low byte of r0 is available as status to the parent process.

`R0` was a general purpose 16-bit register, and the low byte of that would be a full eight bits. And over in `wait` `R0` has the process ID, while the high byte of `MQ` gets the low byte of `R0`, but that's still an 8-bit value.

Comment: This says to me that a historical Unix that truncated to 7 bits would be _abnormal_, but I am going to leave the question open for a few days in case someone remembers that there _was_ one.

Comment: But was the low byte of `R0` treated as signed or unsigned?